# SQL Linked Server Passing Date Parameters

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, parameter

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a linked SQL 2012 Express database.  On the 2008 box I am creating a stored procedure to be used in a report.  I am wanting to pass a date variable so the user can enter a to and from date in reporting services.  However, I have been trying to get the openquery parameter code correct and it's just not happening.  Here is my code:

```
@Custvar VARCHAR(1000),
@fromperiod datetime,
@toperiod datetime

@fromperiod varchar(8),
@toperiod varchar(8)


AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @finalQuery VARCHAR(8000) 

DECLARE @fromperiodvar VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @toperiodvar VARCHAR(8)

--SET @fromperiodvar=(CONVERT(CHAR(8), @fromperiod, 112)) 
--SET @toperiodvar=(CONVERT(CHAR(8), @toperiod, 112)) 


SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY
([ServerName\SQLEXPRESS],'
SELECT
    (DateDiff(DAY ,otrs.dbo.ticket.create_time , otrs.dbo.ticket.change_time) ) AS Open_to_close_days_duration ,
    otrs.dbo.ticket.create_time ,
    otrs.dbo.ticket.change_time,
    otrs.dbo.queue.name
FROM
    otrs.dbo.ticket
    INNER JOIN otrs.dbo.queue
        ON otrs.dbo.ticket.queue_id = otrs.dbo.queue.id
WHERE
    ((((DateDiff(DAY ,otrs.dbo.ticket.create_time ,otrs.dbo.ticket.change_time))) > 0)
        AND((otrs.dbo.ticket.ticket_state_id) = 3 OR(otrs.dbo.ticket.ticket_state_id) = 2 OR(otrs.dbo.ticket.ticket_state_id) = 10))
        AND otrs.dbo.ticket.create_time >= ''''+ @fromperiodvar + '''' and otrs.dbo.ticket.create_time <=''''+ @toperiodvar + ''''
ORDER BY
    otrs.dbo.ticket.queue_id;
')
GO
```

So where am I going wrong?  I am unable to have SQL prompt me for the to and from dates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

For an ad hoc batch, you need to type the date values and assign them to the variables:

```
DECLARE @fromperiod varchar(8),
        @toperiod   varchar(8);

SELECT @fromperiod = '20130101',
       @toperiod = '20130131';
```

An ad hoc T-SQL batch can't prompt you; it's not interactive like VB in a Windows Form. You could do this by using the Debug button on the toolbar, and then editing the values in the Locals tab, but this seems to be a pretty cumbersome way to avoid a little typing:

> [image]

There are probably also ways you could use templates or snippets to have a slightly easier way to input values, but I don't find the above that much of a blocker in the first place.

For Reporting Services, I know there are ways to allow users to enter data and have those passed at parameters, but someone else is going to have to give you the skinny on that ([the documentation might be helpful as well](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx)). I can spell Reporting Services but not much more than that. If this is a stored procedure it probably makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a reason to prefer SELECT over SET in your example?  Coming from a development background SET makes more sense to me...

Comment: @Max only that you can't use `SET` to perform multiple assignments. I find lines and lines of `SET @variable = ` cluttered. I also prefer `SELECT @variable = column FROM dbo.table;` over `SET @variable = (SELECT column FROM dbo.table);` for similar verbosity reasons, and like to be consistent. Unless I'm making a point that something is a single variable assignment, I use `SELECT` pretty consistently.

Comment: Cool.  I figured that was it, but I wasn't 100%.